# aggregating Posts with all their Hashtags using Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have something like Posts in FB/instagram.
When a user searches for something, the input query is used to either find Posts that either have this query in their content, OR - one or more of post's hashtags match this query.

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id int UNIQUE NOT NULL generated always as identity,
    content text,
    content_tokens tsvector,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
    id int UNIQUE NOT NULL generated always as identity,
    tag_title text,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE post_tags(
    post_id int,
    tag_id   int,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (post_id, tag_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (post_id) references posts (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) references tags (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


-- query to find all "relevant" posts :

SELECT posts.id, posts.title, posts.description, tags.id as tag_id, tags.title as tag_title

FROM posts
JOIN post_tags
  ON posts.id = post_tags.post_id
JOIN tags 
  ON tags.id = post_tags.tag_id
  
WHERE tags.title ilike 'user_query'
   OR posts.content_tokens @@ plainto_tsquery('user_query:*');
```

The problem :

I can't figure out how to have Posts returned with a nested array of all its pertinent Tags.
So for example Post -> `{post_id: 123 , tags : [{id: 1, title: a}, {id: 2, title : b}, ...]}`

Also, it results in duplicate records since I can't GROUP BY only by one column (post_id).

Examples:

posts tables has:

```
id    content 
------------------------
1     this is a test
2     this is a test 2
3     this is user_query
```

tags tables has:

```
id   title
---------------
1    user_query
2    something
3    hey
```

post_tags has:

```
post_id    tag_id 
------------------
1          1
1          2
2          2
3          2
3          3
```

So in this example, post_id = 1 has the "user_query" inside one of its tags, and post_id = 3 has the "user_query" inside its content. So, both of them should be returned.

```json
[
  {"post_id" : 1, "tags" : [{"id" : 1, "title": "user_query"}, {"id" : 2, "title" : "something"}]}, 
  {"post_id" : 3, "tags" : [{"id" : 3, "title": "hey"}]}
]
```

Comment: Can you kindly provide sample data and expect output?

Comment: And what you mean can't `group by` , `group by` meant to be used with aggregations and clearly you got none of those in your select clause.

Comment: if you don't want duplicate use `distinct` instead.

Comment: I edited the post with an example data. regarding the DISTINCT, it doesn't solve it (or I just didn't understand how to user it correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want JSON aggrgation?

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.description, 
    JSONB_AGG(JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('id', t.id, 'title', t.title)) as tags
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN post_tags pt ON p.id = pt.post_id
INNER JOIN tags t ON t.id = pt.tag_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: it doesn't have to be JSON per se, I just described the desired result in a json representation for simplicity.
But it would be very beneficial to learn both ways, if it's possible

Comment: @BVtp: if you want to nest the resultset, you need some kind of structured format, such as JSON.

Comment: is it possible to achieve this by employing `array_agg` somehow?

Comment: @BVtp: you want an array of key/value pairs, so JSON seems more appropriate.

Comment: the sql in your answer seems to be missing title and description columns in GROUP BY, but other than that it seems to be working exactly as needed. Thank you very much. I will use this solution.
Also, If it's possible, just as an example to learn and understand those mechanisms better - can you add an example using the `array_agg`? or is it not even possible to achieve similar results with this?

Comment: @BVtp: `id` is the primary key of `posts`, other columns are functionally dependent, so no need to put them in the `group by` clause.

Comment: that's weird, cause I get the following error then `ERROR:  column "p.title" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT p.id, p.title, p.description, `